# How do I globally store a trait object to make it accessible to a C API callback?

Tags: rust

Suppose a C API which calls a callback before returning.  Unfortunately, there is no way to send data to the callback except by global variables.  There is only 1 thread, by the way.

To make this example compile, I've added a dummy implementation for it in Rust, the real thing is extern "C"

```
unsafe fn c_api(c_api_callback:extern fn()){
  c_api_callback();
}
```

I want to encapsulate some state for this API

```
pub trait State {
    fn called(&mut self); //c_api_callback should call this on self
}
```

In a generic way.  Multiple independent implementations of State can exist

```
struct MyState {
    value:i32
}

impl State for MyState{
    fn called(&mut self){
        println!("I hope this prints 123:{}", self.value);
    }
}

pub fn main(){
    let mut mystate = MyState { value: 123 };
    do_call(&mut mystate);
}
```

The basic question: How do I implement what follows?

```
//rustc says: error: explicit lifetime bound required [E0228]
 static static_state:* mut State=0 as *mut State;

//This doesn't work 
//static static_state:*'static mut State=0 as *mut State;
//error: bare raw pointers are no longer allowed, you should likely use `*mut T`, but otherwise `*T` is now known as `*const T`

extern fn my_callback_impl(){
    static_state.called();
}

pub fn do_call(state:&mut State){
    static_state=state;
    unsafe{
        c_api(my_callback_impl);
    }
    static_state=0 as *mut State;
}
```

I tried all kinds of horrible workarounds, up to wrapping the trait in a struct and using transmute on it to cast it to `*u8`, and I have a nice collection of weird error messages and compiler crashes as a result.

As this is the second time I get confused by static in rust, I would also appreciate it if someone has some pointers to blogs or good example code clarifying what's going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `'static` lifetime actually isn't too complicated - it simply denotes that something is guaranteed to live for the *entire life of the program*. In this case, a global value, by definition, needs to be available for that long.

A problem often occurs because people want to initialize that global value during runtime of the program, which means that it *isn't* available for the entire program.

Now, the meat of the problem. Solution presented with very little guarantee on how safe it is.

First, I think you are running into a [bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21397) that prevents you from directly storing the trait object. To work around that, we wrap the trait object in a little dummy struct (`Holder`) that gives the trait object somewhere to live.

Then, we stick the reference to the holder into the *global, mutable, scary,* location. Call the callback, and wham, presto, there it is!

```
use std::mem;

struct Holder<'a>(&'a mut (State + 'a)); //'

// You'd truly better never use this in multiple threads!
static mut static_state: *mut Holder<'static> = 0 as *mut _; //'

pub trait State {
    fn called(&mut self);
}

struct MyState {
    value: i32
}

impl State for MyState{
    fn called(&mut self) {
        println!("I hope this prints 123:{}", self.value);
    }
}

unsafe fn c_api(c_api_callback: extern fn()) {
    c_api_callback();
}

extern fn my_callback_impl() {
    // really should check that it's not 0 here...
    let h = unsafe { &mut *static_state };
    h.0.called();
}

pub fn do_call(state: &mut State){
    let h = Holder(state);
    unsafe {
        // Straight-up lie to the compiler: "yeah, this is static"
        static_state = mem::transmute(&h);
        c_api(my_callback_impl);
        static_state = 0 as *mut _;
    }
}

pub fn main(){
    let mut mystate = MyState { value: 123 };
    do_call(&mut mystate);
}
```

Comment: This looks to easy to be true ;)  I'll check it out, and upvote tomorrow when i've got a chance to test it.  Thanks!  Indeed, scary globals, but my C api has plenty of other scary stuff so I'll live with it.  If someone wants to use a variant of this multithreaded, [s]he'll probably need a thread local.

Comment: Update: Works perfectly. You truly have  a rusty brain.  Thanks.  Minor question:  Why the //' comments ?

Comment: The `//'` comments are to work around Stack Overflow's code highlighter, which doesn't currently handle the `'a` of a namespace well. ^_^